# Fitting a copula vs. directly fitting a multivariate distribution

Tags: copula, density-estimation, multivariate-distribution

I understand that the joint density of two random variables $f(x,y)$ can be decomposed as the product of its marginals and a copula: $f(x,y) = g(x)k(y) \times c(G(x),K(y))$. Alternatively this may be written using CDFs as $F(x,y) = C(G(x),K(y))$.

Is it possible to directly estimate the joint density $f(x,y)$ or the joint distribution $F(x,y)$ without estimating the copula? What are the benefits/costs of obtaining the joint density by first estimating the marginals and copula instead?

Comment: For instance suppose I observe datapoints $x_i,y_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$. Suppose $F(x,y)$ is the multivariate Gaussian distribution. Instead of fitting the associated copula for $F$, could I not directly estimate the parameters of the multivariate Gaussian distribution which maximize the likelihood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to estimate the joint distribution without using copulas. If you know joint distribution, $f(x,y; \Theta) $ up to an unknown parameter vector, $\Theta$, you shouldn't use a copula.

Copulas are useful when you know there is dependence between random variables, but you don't know a joint distribution that can describe this dependence. Say, $g(x) = Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ and $k(y) = Lognormal(\mu, \sigma)$. There is no closed-form expression for $f(x,y)$.  In this case, you can use a copula to estimate the joint distribution from the marginals.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. Based on your response, does it follow that in general copula-based approaches are more flexible in permitting the marginals to be drawn from different distributions?

Comment: Moreover why should copulas not be used if you know the joint distribution $f(x,y;\Theta)$  up to an unknown parameter vector, $\Theta$? If you know both the joint and marginals, shouldn't you in principle be able to back out the joint density exactly by using the copula? Or is some information lost in the process of using copulas which prevents you from backing out the joint dist?

Comment: You have to choose a copula function, $C$, to get the joint distribution. You need to specify $C$ correctly to recover the joint distribution. I think there would be less error if you estimate the joint distribution directly instead of modeling through a copula, but I don't know of any theory which would confirm this.

Comment: How about the case when you know neither the joint distribution nor the copula? A choice will need to be made for either $C$ or $F$ in this case. My intuition is that the copula-based approach might be less restrictive/sensitive to assumptions since you can estimate the marginals non-parametrically; whereas you don't have this flexibility if you assume $F$.

Comment: If you assume a distribution, say multivariate normal, couldn't you estimate the parameters via MLE?

Comment: It then means imposing a specific probability model, which is the same as with copulas.

Comment: Yes indeed, for the multivariate case they are identical because I assumed it. But suppose you are given a vector $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$ and you have no information on the distribution it is drawn from. You need to model the joint distribution. You have enough sample size to estimate the non-parametric marginal distributions, but not enough sample size to estimate the joint distribution non-parametrically. Are you better off non-parametrically estimating the marginals and assuming a copula, or just assuming the joint distribution?

Comment: I guess my question is the following. Provided that you can estimate the marginals non-parametrically: are you more likely to get a better fit if you combine the non-parametric marginals with a copula assumption, or if you assume the entire joint distribution? Do the non-parametric marginals buy us any additional info?

Comment: If you guess right at the joint distribution, it is better. Else, mileage varies...

Comment: Yes, but this does not provide much practical guidance. A correct guess will of course be more accurate than any model-derived estimate. I am trying to see if one method is more likely to yield a better fit of the data.

Comment: I think you're too focused on scenarios when you *could*  specify the joint distribution. The practical use for copulas is when coming up with a joint distribution is impossible. In my example above, there's no joint distribution where the marginals are Gamma and Lognormal.

Comment: Thanks both for your contributions. I believe I have a better grasp now

Comment: In case this is relevant, I have started a new question which involves a new issue I am facing as I try to fit the copula: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583169/how-to-fit-a-copula-when-zeros-abound

Comment: To answer your other question: I believe copula modeling and multivariate density estimation are two ways to approach the same thing. I’m not aware of one approach being universally better than the other.

Comment: Regarding your comment about estimating the margins non-parametrically, it is better to estimate the margins non-parametrically for copula models. There is already some published paper in this regard.

Comment: I was referring to something different, though I may have misinterpreted OP's question. You can estimate a joint distribution using a nonparametric technique like multivariate kernel density estimation. I don't know how this way of estimating the joint density compares to estimating the joint density using a copula. I suspect it converges slower than a copula model.