# How to fit a copula when zeros abound?

Tags: copula, density-estimation, multivariate-distribution

I am modelling a joint distribution for two random variables: $F(x,y)$. I observe $n$ data points $(x^{}_{i},y^{}_{i})^{N}_{i=1}$. I would like to model $F$ as the product of its marginals and a copula: $F(x,y)=g(x)k(y) \times C(G(x),K(y))$.

A problem arises when one or both of the random variables have large numbers of zeros: e.g., if $x$ is earnings and the unemployment rate is $30\%$, then $30\%$ of the sample will have $x=0$. Clearly $G(X)$ will not be uniform since there will be a large spike at $G(0)=.3$. This would appear to violate the definition of a copula in Wikipedia which states that "a copula is a multivariate CDF for which the marginal probability distribution of each variable is uniform on the interval [0, 1]."

Is there a way I can use a copula to fit the joint distribution? It is important that I retain the zeros in the data for my study.

Comment: My first approach would be to try zero-inflated/hurdle-style approaches to separate the zeros from real-valued data.

Comment: This is a general issue : If the marginal distributions are not continuous, the cdf transforms are not uniform.

Comment: If there are zeros values in the data, we usually fit the copula function to the data after removing the zeros.

Comment: Since the zeros are important, I suppose I could separately estimate and amalgamate somehow the three objects: (i) $F(x,y) \ \forall \ x,y >0$; (ii)  $F(x,0)$; and (iii) $F(0,y)$. $f(x,y) \ \forall \ x,y >0$ could  be modelled as $c(G(x),K(y) \mid x,y>0) \tilde{g}(x \mid x>0)\tilde{k}(y \mid y>0) \times g(x>0)k(y>0)$. $f(x,0)$ can be $\tilde{f}(x \mid y=0)k(y=0)$, and  $f(0,y)$ can be similarly defined. The task then reduces to estimating the conditional copulas and marginals, and the probabilities that $x,y$ are zero and greater than 0 respectively. Does this seems like an ok way to proceed?

Comment: @Xi'an The result of the non-uniform transforms is that copulas are not unique when there is discreteness, right?

Comment: I need the joint distribution because it will be used to make monte carlo draws of $x,y$. These draws will be used to compute numerically the integral of $A(x,y)$ over the arguments to get the expectation of $A$.

Comment: It might be that there isn't "the" joint distribution because the joint distribution is not unique. I know that copulas are not unique for discrete marginal distributions, though I am not sure what happens when the margins are mixed between discrete and continuous.

Comment: Couldn't I circumvent the issue of non-uniqueness of the copula by building the joint distribution piecewise as in my comment above? I would only be estimating the copula on non-zero $x,y$ which is continuous

Comment: What about dependence between the zero and nonzero parts of the margins?

Comment: Ignoring the spike at 0, are X and Y continuous or discrete?

Comment: The conditional $\tilde{f}(x∣y=0)$ should capture the dependence between the zero and nonzero parts of the margins. Multiply by $k(y=0)$ and you get the joint density $f(x,0)$.

Comment: Theoretically, $x,y$ are supposed to be drawn from continuous distributions. But in practice there's a spike